# RecyclerView recognize when reaching end of scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` using a horizontal `GridView` with two scrolling buttons on the sides (the app is ment for cars running android so i had to add additional buttons in addition to the ability to scroll the view).

Now I want to be able to dim the buttons when I reach the end of the scrolling, not just the last item, but literaly when there is no more to scroll.

I wasn't able to find a good solution yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello there add this to your code:

**On your activity/fragment/where ever recyclerview is declared**

```
RecyclerView rv; //Add your declare code (findViewById for example)
rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    if (!recyclerView.canScrollHorizontally(1) ) {
        Toast.makeText(ChatDetailsActivity.this,"endOfScroll",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       //Implement button dim here. Example:
       //mybutton.setAlpha(0.5f);

    }
});
```

**EDIT : Not sure if you want to scroll vertically or horizontally
change the word from Horizontally to Vertically in the if statement acording your need**

Comment: can scroll **vertically** ??

Answer (score 0):

in  `onBind()` of **recyclerView adapter**  `if (position==lastItem) { DisableButton.dimButon();}` just add this ...and DisableButton is an Interface containing one method `dimButon();` And in your activity make a field variable `DisableButton dim;` and in your onCreate intialize it using `dim=new DisableButton(....`

Comment: This will cause the button to dim when the last item is shown, I want it to dim **only** when it reaches the end (when scrolling with the finger wont make the view move anymore)